# x:name of the xaml control does not reflects in .xaml.cs file in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm not able to access `x:name` of the element in `.xaml.cs`. It shows this error:

> element name does not exist in the current context.

I tried to clean the solution and also deleted the object directories in obj folder in project but it did not help.

Comment: Check 'x:Class' in xaml and 'namespace classname' in cs first.

Comment: The namespace and the x:Class name are same.

Comment: Could you post the screenshot which contains directory tree, xaml and xaml.cs.

Comment: Is the control in a data template?

Comment: yes it is in data template